# Printing the following series in python

Tags: python, series

Print the following pattern in Python:
20,19,18...1

```
for x in range (21,2):
    x=x-1
    print(x)
```

but when I execute it, the output window comes blank whenever I execute it. I checked the indents too, but still a blank window.
Help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: The `range()` function has a default step of `1`. So your code is trying to go from 21 to 2 by incrementing by 1, which is impossible so it returns nothing. You need to tell it the step: `range(21, 2, -1)` where `-1` is the step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use range like this:

```
range(21,2,-1)
```

Don't include x=x-1

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicit specify that range goes backwards with third value:

```
for x in range(21,1,-1):
    x=x-1
    print(x)
```

and you can change range values that there is no need for `x-=1`:

```
for x in range(20,0,-1):
    print(x)
```